# ExceptionHandler returning JSON or XML not working in spring mvc 3

Tags: exception, spring-mvc

code is like this:

```
   @Controller
    public class TestController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/testerror", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody ErrorTO testerror(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
           throw new ABCException("serious error!");
        }


        @ExceptionHandler(ABCException.class)
        public  @ResponseBody ErrorTO handleException(ABCException ex,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            response.setStatus(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            return new ErrorTO(ex.getMessage());
        }


     @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ErrorTO test(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                      HttpServletResponse response) {
        ErrorTO error = new ErrorTO();
        error.setCode(-12345);
        error.setMessage("this is a test error.");
        return error;
    }

}
```

when I tried curl   -H "Accept:application/json" -v "http://localhost.com:8080/testerror" 
I got this error:
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver - Could not find HttpMessageConverter that supports return type [class com.kibboko.poprocks.appservices.dtos.ErrorTO] and [application/json]

but if I try curl   -H "Accept:application/json" -v "http://localhost.com:8080/test", worked and returned json response.  "application/xml" worked too.

Is there anything special about exception handler I need to take care of so it can work with json or xml? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a known Spring bug (Fixed in 3.1 M1)

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6902

Answer (score 7):

It appears that [`AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.html) has its own array of `HttpMessageConverter`s. You need to configure it to use the same array as used by `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`.

However, it can be complicated when `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` is declared implicitly. Perhaps declaring the following `FactoryBean` may help in all cases:

```
public class AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolverFactoryBean
        implements FactoryBean<AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver> {
    @Autowired
    private AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter a;

    public AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver getObject()
            throws Exception {
        AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver r = new AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver();
        r.setMessageConverters(a.getMessageConverters());
        return r;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: That is really a hassle. Would it be possible to find a simpler solution? Can you give me a working example?

Comment: @Bobo: Have you tried to declare that bean in your context? It should work fine.

Comment: @axtavt: sorry I am a real novice in Spring land. By "declare that bean in your context" you mean declaring it in spring configuration file?

Comment: @axtavt: so Spring uses this FactoryBean when he needs the exceptionResolver, right?! we don't need to call the getObject() manually in the @ExceptionHandler annotated method, right?