# Spring mvc controller null return handler

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Country> getListOfCountries() {

    return countryService.listAll();
}
```

It displays a json view of the object but if the service return null, then I want to display an error message, Any suggestions pls?

Comment: This should work OTB because Jackson will not convert null (last time I checked). That is if your request accept content type is `application/json` you will get an error but not an ideal error. The reason it might appear as an empty string is because your sending the wrong accept mime type. But you really shouldn't return `null` anyway as others have stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, even if this does not directly answer the question, your objects should never ever return **null** instead of empty collections - you can find the reasoning in [Effective Java 2nd Edition](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Edition-ebook), Item 43 / p.201

So, if the situation when no countries were found is normal it must be processed by the client JS code that will check the count and display the respective message.

If something has gone wrong you can throw an exception(as Biju has pointed out +1) - I believe that it's the service who should throw the exception because it knows the reason why it happened, and not to return null anyway.

I'd like to add that in Spring 3.2(in pre Spring 3.2 returning response body is [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097134/spring-exceptionhandler-does-not-work-with-responsebody)) you can set an [@ExceptionHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) that will both return JSON and set the HTTP status code which can be later processed by the client. I think that returning a custom JSON response with some error code is most optimal here.

```
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Country> getListOfCountries() {
        //assuming that your service throws new NoCountriesFoundException();
            //when something goes wrong
            return countryService.listAll();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NoCountriesFoundException.class)
    ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(
                "We are sorry, our server does not know any countries yet.",
                HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT  );
    }
```

Then in the JS code, you can do specific processing depending on the returned status code.

Also, to avoid declaration of the same `@ExceptionHandler` in different controllers, in Spring 3.2 you can put `@ExceptionHandler` inside a `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class.

For details, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-exceptionhandlers and http://www.springsource.org/node/3738 for 3.2 specific things

Comment: +1 He should also configure his Response Converters to not allow ever returning `null` (ie disable the StringConverter) but IIRC this required some painful config in the mvc message converters. It should fail though if his AJAX is setting its `Content Type` correctly because Jackson will not support returning null.

Comment: If the exception occurs in service does the @ExceptionHandler catch on controller?

Comment: @user1827614 If the exception occurs in the service method, it will be propagated down the stack to the controller method(if the service method was called from the controller of course).

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options I think:

1. If you return a null back, it will be returned as an empty string "", you can probably look for that and handle it.
2. Return a wrapper type on top of your list, this way if the wrapped list is null something like this will be returned back to the client `{"countries":null}` which can be more easily handled at the javascript end.
3. Throw an exception, which will propagate as a 500 status code back to the client, you can then have an error handler on the javascript side to handle this scenario.