# ControllerAdvice ExceptionHandler not called from PropertyEditorSupport

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

I'm using Spring 3.2.1 and have a `PropertyEditorSupport` to force a parameter I'd like autoconverted to an enum to uppercase so it converts wrong-cased parameters. An `IllegalArgumentException` can be thrown if the parameter String can't be converted to the enum. My problem is that the status code is returned as 500 when it ought to be 400. I created a `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and with a method annotated `@ExceptionHandler (IllegalArgumentException.class)`, intending to set the status code there, but the method is never called when the exception is thrown. Why not? Is it the same problem as discussed here, [MaxUploadSizeExceededException doesn't invoke the exception handling method in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298265/maxuploadsizeexceededexception-doesnt-invoke-the-exception-handling-method-in-s) ? i.e.

> "...the exception is thrown before the request has reached the
>   dispatcher servlet. Therefore your exceptionhandler isn't called
>   because at the point the exception is thrown the target controller has
>   yet to be determined."

If so how can I return the proper status code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version:

Put `@ExceptionHandler(Exception)` annotated method in `@Controller` class.

---

Longer version:

I noticed that the `@ExceptionHandler(XxxException.class)` annotated method in `@ControllerAdvice` class will only be called if `XxxException` happens "after" entering the method with matching `@RequestMapping`.

Conditions like `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` and `MethodArgumentNotValidException` will cause SpringMVC to NOT enter the `@RequestMapping` method, so advice is not applied.

My solution was to sadly place `@ExceptionHandler(XxxException.class)` annotated method in the actual controller class. Not nice but works.

Hope this helps. If someone knows of a better solution (when using `@ControllerAdvice`), do share.