# Spring 3.2 @ExceptionHandler @ResponseBody JSON Response Via Jackson

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-3

Please help me to send JSON Response for the @ExceptionHandler.
As far as i understand i need to configure the view resolver which handles response for this method.
Please have a look at my code. Controller Advice:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import com.models.ValidationErrorDTO;

@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler {

    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    public RestErrorHandler(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationErrorDTO processValidationError(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        System.out.println("IN THE EXCEPTION HANDLER !!!!");
        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

        return processFieldErrors(fieldErrors);
    }

    private ValidationErrorDTO processFieldErrors(List<FieldError> fieldErrors) {
        ValidationErrorDTO dto = new ValidationErrorDTO();

        for (FieldError fieldError : fieldErrors) {
            String localizedErrorMessage = resolveLocalizedErrorMessage(fieldError);
            dto.addFieldError(fieldError.getField(), localizedErrorMessage);
        }

        return dto;
    }

    private String resolveLocalizedErrorMessage(FieldError fieldError) {
        Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        String localizedErrorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(fieldError,
                currentLocale);

        // If the message was not found, return the most accurate field error
        // code instead.
        // You can remove this check if you prefer to get the default error
        // message.
        if (localizedErrorMessage.equals(fieldError.getDefaultMessage())) {
            String[] fieldErrorCodes = fieldError.getCodes();
            localizedErrorMessage = fieldErrorCodes[0];
        }
        System.out.println("THE MESSAGE IS :: " + localizedErrorMessage);
        return localizedErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

Jackson View Resolver that i have in my application.

```
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
<bean id="jacksonSerializationConfig" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig"
    factory-bean="jacksonObjectMapper" factory-method="getSerializationConfig" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="jacksonSerializationConfig" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setSerializationInclusion" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value type="org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion">NON_DEFAULT</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now I guess i need to add something like this to get the @ResponseBody Work for the @ExceptionHandler methods.

```
<!-- JSON format support for Exception -->
    <bean id="methodHandlerExceptionResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
```

But i have no idea, how it is internally working, Please help !!

This is the error i am getting :

```
02:09:28,030 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public com.models.ValidationErrorDTO com.RestErrorHandler.processValidationError(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException): org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:126) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:321) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1148) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:985) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
```

References : 
http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api/

[Spring @ExceptionHandler does not work with @ResponseBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097134/spring-exceptionhandler-does-not-work-with-responsebody)

http://www.waheedtechblog.in/2013/01/how-exceptionhandler-return-json-in.html

Comment: does [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.jp/2014/07/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc.html) helps you

Comment: How are you testing this? Are you using curl? If yes, what's the curl command that you're using?

Comment: @Alind Billore, I'm facing a similar issue with Spring 3.2. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Lizzie Sorry for late reply, i posted the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, My error was resolved by the answer i posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add the getters and setters for the Object that you are going to return.

The tutorial that i followed omitted the getters and this whole thing didn't work.

So for me this was it !

Comment: I've got a similar problem, can you please tell me what object are you returning and where did you put the getters?

Comment: Whatever is your return type of the method, what you actually want to be returned as a JSON, that class MUST have getters and setters. So that Jackson can get those fields and convert it into a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do this:
in controller

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(DataException e, HttpServletResponse response) {
    log.error(e);
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    if (e.getRootCause() instanceof SQLException) {
        SQLException s = (SQLException) e.getRootCause();
        return CommonUtil.getErrorResponse(ErrorToResponse.getJsonSqlError(s.getMessage(), s.getSQLState()));
    } else {
        log.error(e);
        return CommonUtil.getErrorResponse(ErrorToResponse.getJsonError(e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

where getErrorResponse return new ResponseEntity and getJsonSqlError() return json-string

Then add

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and maven dependencie:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Its work for me.