# Serialize exceptions to JSON with spring-mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(..)
@ResponseBody
public SearchResponse search(SearchRequest request) throws SearchException { .. }
```

I want to return to the requester:

- JSON-serialized search response in case everything is fine
- JSON-serialized exception details if `SearchException` is thrown.

The first part works fine (having Jackson on the classpath and `<mvc:annotation-driven />`) but I don't see an easy way to serialize the exception as json.

I can register a custom handler, and write a JSON string from there, but I may also need XML serialization, which will mean I'll need conditionals in the handler. Isn't there something ready for that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948627/exceptionhandler-returning-json-or-xml-not-working-in-spring-mvc-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what worked: I took [axtavt's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948627/exceptionhandler-returning-json-or-xml-not-working-in-spring-mvc-3/4948985#4948985) (annotating it with `@Component`), and added this method to the controller:

```
@ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
public @ResponseBody CustomException handleException(CustomException ex) {
    return ex;
}
```

Comment: It works since Spring 3.1, it doesn't work under Spring 3.0 : https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6902